# How to use Wire.find And Wire.findUntil on arduino?

Tags: arduino, eeprom

I would like to retrieve some objects from a Json document store in an EEPROM 24LC32 memory without being forced to read and insert the content of the EEPROM memory into the small RAM of my arduino using Wire.find and Wire.findUntil. Thank you for your help

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/

Comment: Yes, I have seen that before. But I would like an example of use for Wire.find and Wire.findUntil. Thank you

Comment: don't store JSON to EEPROM. it is usual to store data in EEPROM in binary form

Comment: Json data will be converted to messagepack before being backed up on EEPROM memory, and it's to better manage that data that I use Json upstream. It's to analyze the data without having to load them all into the RAM that I need help 